# Mapreduce job has only map phase showing no Mapoutput records =0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-kafka

I have a code for mapreduce job which has only map phase. Its function is to read the file and publish it to the kafka topic. When we see the logs of this job after successful execution, it does write to the kafka topic successfully but it doesnt show the map output records(i.e., shows map output records =0) and map input records match the file. What is the reason of not showing the map output records incorrectly here. The process is working as expected without any problem in publishing the data to topic.

Comment: Please add relevant code here

Comment: Why are you using MapReduce to do this, anyway? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html

Comment: The code is in production already. It does read files on hdfs and does some appends before the message sent to kafka.